# Phase measurement in multiplexed system

Tags: adc

Can you perform valid phase measurement with data obtained using a multiplexed system without anti aliasing filters?

Comment: How it is being multiplexed? What are the signals? Why can't you have an anti aliasing filter?

Comment: acquired data to 500 Hz. System used was a multiplexed system without anti aliasing filters

Comment: Phase of what with reference to what?

Comment: from one channel to another

Comment: You still haven't said how it was multiplexed. What are these 2 channels? Is one just a fixed frequency. Step back and give us context to what it is you are doing.

Comment: Nevermind, It is only a  general question for my class. I have not more details. Thanks

Comment: @Rosa  I think that your question is perfectly valid and a good mental exercise.  More to the point, this is not an uncommon issue to encounter in the real world where many data-acquisition systems use ADC's with integrated multiplexers.

Comment: @DavidKessner I didn't gather that it was a multiplexed ADC. That does make a lot more sense though.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can perform valid phase measurements with a multiplexed ADC.  But it requires some math.

The most straightforward way is to implement a fractional-sample delay and apply this to all channels of your multiplexed ADC.  In this way you time-align the channels so that they are all have an even phase alignment.

The fractional delay isn't as difficult as it sounds.  Essentially you upsample to a higher sample rate and then decimate back down to the original sample rate (but in a way that gives you the fractional delay that you need).  I won't go into super detail here, since this is somewhat beyond the scope that can be answered in such a forum.  But I'll give you a reasonable overview.

Let's say that your multiplexed ADC has 8 input channels.  You will then want to upsample by 8x.  (4 channels = 4x, etc.)  Start by inserting 7 "zero values" between each of your samples.  Then run this through a low-pass-filter with the cutoff frequency set to 1/2 of your original sample rate.  Next, do a gain adjustment by multiplying each sample by 8 (or 4, or whatever).  And then decimate back to the original sample rate by throwing out 7 of 8 samples (or keeping 1 of every 8 samples).

When you decimate, make sure you throw out the correct 7 samples.  If you do this right the result will be 8 (or 4 or whatever) streams that are in perfect time alignment.

Note:  Technically speaking, one channel doesn't need this done to it.  Even so, I recommend doing this to all 8 channels.  This way if your low-pass-filter introduces any delay then it will be constant for all channels and your phase information will be preserved.

There are some optimizations that you can do to speed this up.  You can combine the 8x gain adjustment into the low pass filter, eliminating this step.  Next, if you use a FIR filter for your low-pass-filter then you can simply not generate the 7 samples that you're going to throw out anyway.  Also, since 7 of each 8 samples going into the FIR are zero you can optimize the algorithm to not do those multiply-accumulates.

Terms to Google for more information are:  sample-rate converter, FIR filter, polyphase filter.

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that the lack of an antialising filter doesn't really factor into the problem.  The input to the ADC/Mux cannot have any frequency content that is above the Nyquist limit.  An antialising filter is used to remove these frequencies.  If those frequencies are not present in the first place then a filter is not required.  All of this is true reguardless of if there is multiplexing involved or not.